# String to array filled with chars

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have a string similar to the following:

```
var mystring = "aasfeeeffdbals";
```

and I need to make it an array filled with the individual chars. I know what I can do that with the following method:

```
var charArray = []
for (var i = 0; i<mystring.length; i++) {
    charArray.push(mystring[i]);
}
```

**QUESTION:** My understanding of a string is that it already in essence is an array of characters put together, so might there be a more straight forward way of creating a new `array` with the characters from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var chars = "aasfeeeffdbals".split('');` will bring you wanted result